# Permission denial causing app crash in Ionic

Tags: android, cordova, parse-platform, ionic-framework

I have been confused by a random crash in my app since I updated to cordova 5 and started using crosswalk.

This is my `logcat`:

```
D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController( 1110): refreshSignalCluster - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController( 1110): refreshSignalCluster: data=-1 bt=false
D/STATUSBAR-IconMerger( 1110): checkOverflow(1344), More:false, Req:false Child:5
W/ActivityManager(  891): Permission Denial: getCurrentUser() from pid=32252, uid=10037 requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS
I/ActivityManager(  891): Process com.tesingguru.tesing_Guru (pid 29852) (adj 0) has died.
I/WindowState(  891): WIN DEATH: Window{42fb82c0 u0 com.tesingguru.tesing_Guru/com.tesingguru.tesing_Guru.MainActivity}
I/SurfaceFlinger(  329): id=3847 Removed NainActivit (16/29)
I/SurfaceFlinger(  329): id=3847 Removed NainActivit (-2/29)
I/FactoryTest(  891): isRunningFactoryApp=false
I/FactoryTest(  891): isRunningFactoryApp=false
W/ActivityManager(  891): Force removing ActivityRecord{4303e860 u0 com.tesingguru.tesing_Guru/.MainActivity t221}: app died, no saved state
```

I am completely confused by this? The line I am suspecting is:

```
W/ActivityManager(  891): Permission Denial: getCurrentUser() from pid=32252, uid=10037 requires android.permission.
```

Comment: If you've tried the usual cleanup (clean and rebuild the project, reboot the test devices, etc), maybe it's a Cordova bug.  I think INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS is a system-level permission (that you can't request unless you're signed with the system signature), but I could be wrong.  Do you have any idea if you're using a feature that might need to get the user or user name?

Comment: Taylorsuk any updates on this? Experiencing the same effects. What device are you using? I'm seeing it on a Galaxy Tab 4 on which its SIM has expired.

Comment: @MikeMurko unfortunately I cannot remember the specific steps I did to solve this issue (and it was on a Galaxy Tab 4 also) however I seem to recall the following: remove platforms, uninstall Cordova / clean cache etc etc upgrade ionic lib. Basically clean and clear before re-adding everything. Also remember a move away from crosswalk and using the standard APK rather than X86 or whatever it is... Sorry I cannot be of more help, but it is solvable.

Comment: @MikeMurko now I read my own question again I remember I didn't bother with crosswalk anymore. It helped on the Galaxy Tab 4 but caused issues. I just keep my fingers crossed for native chromium browsers on my clients devices and try and optimise as much as possible for the standard browser.